# Java - JDBC driver and MySQL database connection issues

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Ok - I found the driver version that goes with the database.. however now I get the following.

> Got an exception!  Communications link
>   failure due to underlying exception:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.net.ConnectException MESSAGE:
>   Connection timed out: connect
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: connect
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:372)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:215)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:271)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1555)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
>           at freelancebillingapp.customerInfoUI.jButton1MouseClicked(customerInfoUI.java:221)
>           at freelancebillingapp.customerInfoUI.access$000(customerInfoUI.java:12)
>           at freelancebillingapp.customerInfoUI$1.mouseClicked(customerInfoUI.java:59)
>           at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:253)
>           at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6266)
>           at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3255)
>           at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
>           at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4247)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
>           at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> Last packet sent to the server was 1
>   ms ago.

Comment: ** I forgot to add - I tried disabling my firewall (zonealarm) but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Wait a sec - you've got a mysql database open to the entire internet on a standard port?  Are you *asking* to get hacked?

Comment: And watch out for customers named "Little Bobby Tables".  You're asking for an injection attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5350509) may not solve it, but it tells you that someone else has had this problem.

Make sure you have the precise version of JDBC driver to match your version of MySQL.

I would strongly urge you to rewrite your code more like this.  You aren't closing resources properly at all.

Adapt it to your own needs.  I created a local MySQL database on my machine and added a customer table.  It worked just fine.

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DatabaseUtils
{
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/contacts";
    private static final String USERNAME = "contacts";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "contacts";

    public static final String SELECT_SQL = "select customer_id, name, street, city, state, zip, phone, url from customer order by customer_id";
    public static final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into customer(name, street, city, state, zip, phone, url) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection connection = null;

        try
        {
            connection = getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            List<Map> rows = findAllCustomers(connection);

            for (Map row : rows)
            {
                System.out.println(row);                    
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            close(connection);
        }
    }

    public static List<Map> findAllCustomers(Connection connection) throws SQLException
    {
        List<Map> rows = new ArrayList<Map>();
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try
        {
            st = connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL);
            rs = st.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                rows.add(map(rs));                
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            close(rs);
            close(st);
        }

        return rows;
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> map(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        Map<String, Object> row = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();

        int numColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numColumns; ++i)
        {
            String column = meta.getColumnName(i);
            Object value = rs.getObject(i);
            row.put(column, value);
        }

        return row;
    }

    public static Connection getConnection(String url, String username, String password) throws SQLException
    {
        Driver driver = DriverManager.getDriver(url);

        DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);

        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(Statement st)
    {
        try
        {
            if (st != null)
            {
                st.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet rs)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rs != null)
            {
                rs.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void rollback(Connection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can mysql accept network connections?  When you connect with the "mysql" command line program, you're not doing a network connection, but when you do with JDBC you are making a network connection.  Try using "-h localhost" in your mysql command line to see.

Comment: Yes - the database is hosted on a godaddy server and I haven't had any problems connecting to this database or others hosted on the same server with other programs.  I just reinstalled windows 7 and the jdbc driver, I don't know if maybe something installed wrong?  I've never had this error happen before.  If it matters - I am using netbeans to build the program.

Comment: Netbeans is immaterial.  I wouldn't like being able to connect directly to a database over the Internet this way.

Comment: @Jason, I'd say then that @duffymo has it right and throwing random versions of the JDBC driver at the problem aren't going to help - you've got to get the one that came with that version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
            /*
             Connection
             */


            import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
            import java.sql.DriverManager;


            public class PersonalConnection {

                private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
                private String schema = "database name";
                private String uname = "";
                private String password = "";
                private Connection connection;

                public Connection openConnection() {
                    try {
                        try {
                            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        }
                        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url + schema, uname, password);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    return connection;
                }

                public void closeConneciton() {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }

                }
            }

        /* Servlet */



          response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    DetailsBean db = new DetailsBean();

                    String name = request.getParameter("name");
                    String countryname = request.getParameter("countryname");
                    String statename = request.getParameter("statename");

                    db.setName(name);
                    db.setCountry(countryname);
                    db.setState(statename);

                    DetailsManager dm = new DetailsManager();
                    String result = dm.insertDetailsManager(db);
                    if (result.equals("true")) {
                       /* RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("StateDetails.jsp?name=" + db.getName());
                        rd.forward(request, response);*/
                        response.sendRedirect("StateDetails.jsp");
                    } else {
                        out.print(result);
                    }

        /*  DAO */



        /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */


        import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
        import java.sql.PreparedStatement;


        import java.sql.ResultSet;


        public class DetailsDAO {

            private Connection connection;
            private PersonalConnection con;

            public DetailsDAO() {
                con = new PersonalConnection();
            }

            public String insertRecordDAO(DetailsBean db) {

                int rowcount=0;
                try {
                    connection=con.openConnection();
                    String query = "INSERT INTO personal_details(user_name,country_name,state_name) values(?,?,?);";
                    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ps.setString(1, db.getName());
                    ps.setString(2, db.getCountry());
                    ps.setString(3, db.getState());
                    rowcount = ps.executeUpdate();
                    if(rowcount==1)
                    {
                        return "true";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "false";
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return ex+"";

                } finally {
                    con.closeConneciton();
                }
            }

            public ResultSet getGetails() throws Exception
            {
                connection=con.openConnection();
                String query="SELECT * from state_details";
                PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
                return rs;
            }
        }

    /*Manager*/

    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class DetailsManager {

        DetailsDAO detdao = new DetailsDAO();

        public String insertDetailsManager(DetailsBean db) {
            String rowcount = detdao.insertRecordDAO(db);
            return rowcount;
        }



    }

/*Bean*/


/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */



public class DetailsBean {

    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String state;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


}
```